# MongoDB alter field

Tags: mongodb

I have an collection "companies" and the documents have this structure:

id, name, address, branch, city

I want to add an keyword field that will have an index, so I can do a fulltext search, but how can I add a field to each document?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no schema in MongoDB, so you don't have to add a field to every document.
Just start writing new documents with this field, or update  old documents when you have this value for them.

As for indexing, now you can leverage [sparse indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-SparseIndexes), they will be more efficient if most of your documents don't have this field.

Also, you might want this `keyword` field to be an array. It can be handled more efficiently than a string.

If you want to add a field with the same value to **all** documents in a collection, you can use this:

```
db.collection.update({}, // update all documents
                    {$set : {keyword : []}}, // or another value
                    false, // is upsert?
                    true)  // is multi-update?
```

When you do a `$set`, you can't use values from other fields. So if this new value is going to be a function of other fields, you have no other option, but to loop through the documents and update them one by one.

Comment: But I need to update the current documents and add another field called "keyword" as I mentioned in my question, so its not related to a schema, I just want to know how I can update all these documents with a new field combining the values of the 'name', 'address' branch and city field.

Comment: You have to loop through the documents and update them one by one. You can't use values of other fields when you set a field (like we used to in SQL)